# Need Microsoft office installed on server for Java EE application

Tags: import, ms-word, apache-poi

I wanted to know do we need Microsoft office installed on server in order to generate word, excel, pdf documents from Java EE application.

As I understand the pdf is generated by iText so there is no need of anything there but for Excel, Word or any other open office document does it happen through library or do we need office applications installed on server?

Secondly, in case of heavy load of generating let us say 500 documents will this component handle it?

Comment: It depends upon the library that this "J2EE Server" is using. If said library requires the Microsoft Office COM+ servers (e.g. Component Model exposed by Office) and other Office libraries, then yes. Otherwise, probably not. **tldr; read the requirements for the libraries being used**

Comment: Also, 500 documents is practically no work to a computer and the number of documents is irrelevant (if anything it only takes more time). There might be size limitation of a particular document for some *very* large documents/sources; but *see documentation/limitations specific to iText*.

Comment: Thanks. My application is creating document using Apache POI api (http://poi.apache.org/). and its deploy on jboss and tomcat server. Thanks for mention iText point, sure I will check.

Comment: @pst I don't have a idea about other Office libraries. according to this specification, other Office libraries are still required?

Comment: POI does not depend upon Office installations. (Note how *none* of the documentation or FAQs list such a requirement ..)